# JW player time slider

Tags: actionscript-3, jwplayer

I want to place *JW time slider* at top of controlbar like on youtube.

I am trying to edit `JW` source to achieve this, but cant find where it declares this 3 positions (`'left'`,`'center'`,`'right'`) and add my own position.

*Where must I start looking for this?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to edit Slider.as, ControlbarLayoutManager.as

Answer (score 0):

See the jwplayer [build your own skin page](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28849/skin-xml-reference). May this will help you.